# Is there a way to test an api request before post first?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have made this code in python using requests, to get data to an api in a site, and it works well:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': api_key
}

# Read the contents of the file into a variable
files = {
    'file_input': open(file_name, 'rb'),
}

# Create a dictionary of parameters to pass to the API
payload = {
    'title': title_name,
    'type': 3
}

# Make the API request using requests.post()
response = requests.post(UPLOAD_URL, files=files,
                         headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Is there a way to test first if the "title" or part of it exists already, before the post?

i have tried using get:

```
requests.get
```

but it asks for the full payload, and i want only the title.

Comment: `head()` or `options()` maybe?

Comment: Your question should be: does that api provide a GET call for the title? But that would be a question for the api provider, not for stack overflow :-)

Comment: you are right GET method is not supported!